# Accesibility of modified EC2 instances

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

[This page on EC2 documentation site](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2006-10-01/GettingStartedGuide/creating-an-image.html) describes how to modify and store an EC2 instance. What it does not specify is whether the resulting instance is publicly available or not. How, and where do you configure public availability of your custom EC2 instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EC2 Developer Guide: How to Make an AMI Public](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?sharingamis-public.html)

AMIs are private by default, but this page also shows how to make sure that they are.

You can also visually confirm an AMI's status by using the "Private Images" filter in the [EC2 Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/) or looking at the "Visibility" field in [Elasticfox](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=609).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the document says that the AMI is private to your account in the next-to-last paragraph.

Comment: the actual wording is 

"You now have your very own image"

I also have my very own car, face, t-shirt etc, but they all are publicly visible. If I install sensitive software on "my very own" image, I don't want it to be visible by others.

Comment: I disagree: the wording is "This custom AMI is private to your account." This appears directly after the sentence you quote.